# Why do I get 'cannot find module' error when the relative path is correct?

Tags: typescript, file, visual-studio-code, jestjs, path

This is a Next.js app.

Inside Root, there are two folders, test and src.

From a file inside test folder, I import a module(next.js page) inside src.

[image]

I call
`import AnalysisCategoriesPage from '../src/pages/admin/report/analysis-categories/index';`

However, the error I get says
`Cannot find module '../src/pages/admin/report/analysis-categories/index' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)`

I am using Jest/Testing library.

My tsconfig file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*.ts", "./src/**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "./public", "dist"],
  "paths": {
    "src": ["./src"]
  },
  "linterOptions": {
    "exclude": []
  }
}
```

package.json's Jest declaration:

```
"jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^src/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
    },
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom"
  },
```

Note, the other files such as the one in admin - calculations do get imported.

So this got me thinking the `'/[reportName]'` portion may be messing with this?

When running the test, I get this error:

```
Cannot find module '../src/pages/admin/report/analysis-categories/index' from 'test/admin-analysis-categories.test.tsx'
```

I would really appreciate any suggestions.

THank you.

Comment: update: when running the test, I get this error: Cannot find module '../src/pages/admin/report/analysis-categories/index' from 'test/admin-analysis-categories.test.tsx'